# Responsive text over image

Tags: html, css

Whenever i place my text over the image and go into mobile view, I get this happening(see image below) Ideally i need the text, and button, to change on screen size? althoguh i have tried placing this in which did nothing

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
p {
font-size: 10px;
}
}
```

This is the HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="acc">
<img class="img-responsive img-center" src="img/SECC.png" width="960px">
<div class="overlay">

<p id="SECC">SECC, Glasgow</p>
    <p id="SECCSub1">

    Friday 28 November 2015</p>


    <p id="SECCSub2">Saturday 29 November 2015</p>

    <p id="SECCSub3">Sunday 30 November 2015</p>

    <p id="SECCbutton"><button class="buttontest">BUY TICKETS</button></p>
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
.acc{
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    height: 300px
}
.overlay {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
    #SECC
{
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 35pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 30%;
    top: 0%
}


#SECCSub1
{
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 35%;
    top: 34%;
}
#SECCSub2
{
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 33%;
    top: 41%;
}
#SECCSub3
{
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 34%;
    top: 48%;
}
#SECCbutton
{
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 37%;
    top: 65%;
}
```

I don't have the Rep to post an image so here is the link to it
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZCW8.png

Comment: link to actual site? You might be able to just do ```@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {p {font-size: 10px!important;}}```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
p {
   font-size: 10px!important;
 }
}
```

I threw it in a JS fiddle and `!important` made the live view react.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have enough importance to be read, because the CSS is being set with ID's. Remember that media queries don't add specificity.

You need to either use: `font-size: 10px !important;`, or better yet, reference each ID.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  p, #SECC, #SECCSub1, #SECCSub2, #SECCSub3, SECCbutton {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

If you go that route, make sure the media query is at the bottom of the CSS document.